# Compare and index regex in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have two arrays:

```
enteredCommands = ["valid", "this", 1.1];
validParameters = [/valid/, /alsoValid/, /this|that/, /\d+(\.)?\d*/];
```

I want to loop through all of the `enteredCommands`, if it exists in `validParameters` remove it from `validParameters`, if it doesn't, break.

I don't know how to compare the regex in this way, if I change `validParameters` to:

`validParameters = ["valid", "alsoValid", /this|that/, /\d+(\.)?\d*/];`

and use:

```
var ok2go = true;
// For each entered command...
for (var i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
     // Check to see that it is a valid parameter
     if (validParameters.indexOf(commands[i]) === -1) {
         // If not, an invalid command was entered.
         ok2go = false;
         break;
     // If valid, remove from list of valid parameters so as to prevent duplicates.
     } else {
         validParameters.splice(validParameters.indexOf(commands[i]), 1);
     }
     return ok2go;
}

if (ok2go) {
   // do stuff if all the commands are valid
} else {
   alert("Invalid command");
}
```

It works the way I want it to for the strings, but obviously not for those values that need to be regex. Is there any way to solve this?

Test cases:

```
enteredCommands = ["valid", "this", 1.1, 3];
// Expected Result: ok2go = false because 2 digits were entered

enteredCommands = ["valid", "alsoValid", "x"];
// Expected Result: ok2go = false because x was entered

enteredCommands = ["valid", "alsoValid", 1];
// Expected Result: ok2go = true because no invalid commands were found so we can continue on with the rest of the code
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Not at all clear what you are asking or wanting to accomplish

Comment: The wanted result is just to verify that all of the `enteredCommands` exist in `validParameters` only once. Hence: "I want to loop through all of the `enteredCommands`, if it exists in `validParameters` remove it from `validParameters`, if it doesn't, break."

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the given commands and if a regular expression match, the exclude it from the regex array. Return only commants which does not match with the rest of the regex array.

```js
function check(array) {
    var regex = [/valid/, /alsoValid/, /this|that/, /\d+(\.)?\d*/];

    return array.filter(function (a) {
        var invalid = true;
        regex = regex.filter(function (r) {
            if (!r.test(a)) {
                return true;
            }
            invalid = false;     
        });
        invalid && alert('invalid command: ' + a);
        return invalid;
    });
}

console.log(check(["valid", "this", 1.1, 3]));   // 2 digits were entered
console.log(check(["valid", "alsoValid", "x"])); // x was entered
console.log(check(["valid", "alsoValid", 1]));   // nothing, no invalid commands were found
```

Comment: This doesn't address if `enteredCommands` includes something like `"x"`, in which case I want to alert that an invalid command was entered.

Comment: please add some test cases to the question and what should happen. actually this answer checks `enteredCommands` in advance, if an invalid command is entered.

Comment: Added test cases, the goal isn't necessarily to remove things from `validParameters`, its just to do syntax checking before the rest of the function that this will live in executes.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you split up the checks for a matching regex and the check for a matching string.

Conceptually, you might want to do the following (code not tested)

```
var validStringParameters = ["valid", "alsoValid"];
var validRegexMatches = [/valid/, /alsoValid/, /this|that/, /\d+(\.)?\d*/];

var validCommands = enteredcommands.filter(function(command){
if (validStringParameters.indexOf(command) !== -1){
return true;
}
for (var i = 0; i < validRegexMatches.length; i++){
if (command.test(validRegexMatches[i]){
return true;
})
return false;
}
})
```